# Forward an email to another email account with a specific Reply-To

Tags: php, email, cpanel, imap

I need to forward emails incoming from one email address to another email address, while keeping a copy on the original server, and I also need that the email forwarded is provided with a specific Reply-To.

I tried this with cPanel's forwarder, it gets the jobs done, but I can't specify any Reply-To for incoming forwarded emails. So I thought to achieve this with plain PHP, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are you sending an email from PHP and therefore need to include a BCC and define the ReplyTo Address?

Comment: No, I'm trying to avoid manually sending because I'd need to specify the "From" address with the original email sender and applying a Reply-To, but that's giving me a "Sender verify failed", so I was wondering if there's some imap specific function to just copy the email to another account and editing the header to add the Reply-To attribute